# Does the verb "scendere" need "avere" or "essere"?

Tags: verbs, sentences, auxiliary-verb

I read a book (*Io non ho paura*, Niccolò Ammaniti) and I read a strange thing:

> Gli occhi mi sono riempiti di lacrime, ho aperto la porta e ho sceso le scale.

Why? Shouldn't it be "Sono sceso dalla scala"?

---

Ho letto un libro (*Io non ho paura*,  Niccolò Ammaniti) e ho letto una strana cosa:

> Gli occhi mi sono riempiti di lacrime, ho aperto la porta e ho sceso le scale.

Perché? Non dovrebbe essere "Sono sceso dalla scala"?

Comment: Hi. If your first language is Italian, you may well ask your questions in Italian.

Comment: Whyte? I would improve my English writing a Italian question in English.

Comment: There are SE sites more suitable to improve one's English, such as [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/) and [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Very few of us are English mother tongue here, and we might not be able to correct and improve your English (nor feel bound to).

Comment: Moreover, if you are, or understand, Italian, please read a [dictionary article](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scendere/). It will answer your questions; if any doubt remains, we'll still be here.

Comment: Un'osservazione su “scendere dalle scale”. È corretto anch'esso (così come “scendere le scale”), ma è ambiguo: potrebbe voler dire sia “scendere usando le scale” (come quando si dice “scendere dalla porta centrale”) che “allontanarsi dalla scale scendendone” (per esempio, le scale sono pericolanti ed è meglio passare sulla rampa che c'è accanto).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Scendere* can be both intransitive and transitive. The transitive meanings are:

- **Going down something:** this is the case you found in the book: *scendere le scale* = *going down the stairs*
- **Bringing down something:** used in some local dialects: *«Scendi lo zaino»* = *«Bring down the backpack»*.

As a reference, [Treccani online dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scendere/) has for **scendere⁴**:

> **4.** *tr.* **a.** Percorrere in discesa: *sc. le scale, un’erta, un pendìo; fece un salto, scese il letto in furia (Manzoni)*. **b.** *region.* Calare, spostare o portare in basso: *rinvoltammo il padrone dentro una pelliccia e delle coperte, lo scendemmo e caricammo nella macchina (Palazzeschi); l’avevamo sceso [il carro] dal crocevia e sistemato molto bene tra i cespugli (Arpino)*.

Transitive verbs in Italian require mostly the auxiliary *avere*, and *scendere* makes no exception.

A number of related questions on the internet, as well as this very question and my previous erroneous answer, show that the transitive form of *scendere* is perceived as wrong by some native speakers. This is probably an instance of [hypercorrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection), due to the transitive form being used often in its second meaning in southern dialects (see also [l'ipercorrettismo e i dialetti](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipercorrettismo#L.27ipercorrettismo_e_i_dialetti)).

[An article](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/entrare-uscire-salire-scendere-transitivi-fu) by *Accademia della Crusca* about the transitive forms of *entrare*, *uscire*, *salire*, *scendere*, while being concerned mainly with new and dialectal forms, states in the second-last paragraph that transitive forms of *scendere* are correct: *«[Salire e scendere] ammettono anche in lingua la possibilità di un uso transitivo e quindi [...] richiedono l’ausiliare avere: sono salito da te e sono sceso all'alba, ma anche **ho salito la gradinata** e **ho sceso le scale**»*.

Also, [an article](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_971.html) on the Treccani website answering this same question states that the transitive form is correct and its meaning can be different from that of the intransitive form *«sono sceso dalle scale»*, as pointed out by @DaG in a comment.

---

### Historical usage

[image: ngram for "avere_INF sceso,Avere_INF sceso"]

[The graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avere_INF%20sceso%2CAvere_INF%20sceso&year_start=1600&year_end=2016&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cavere_INF%20sceso%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Baveva%20sceso%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bha%20sceso%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavere%20sceso%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bho%20sceso%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babbiamo%20sceso%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavevano%20sceso%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhanno%20sceso%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHo%20sceso%3B%2Cc0) from google ngrams shows occurences dating back to 1808, but they come from even older texts, like Galileo Galilei's *Dialogo sopra i due massimi sistemi del mondo* (1632): *«[due pietre] fusser talmente differenti nelle loro velocità, che [...] l'altra si trovasse non **avere** né anco **sceso** dieci braccia»*

Use of the *passato prossimo* is more recent, yet old enough to be accepted as correct. This is probably due to this tense becoming increasingly common through the last century. The form is also used by many classical authors, as pointed out by @DaG. An example by Eugenio Montale: *«**Ho sceso**, dandoti il braccio, almeno **un milione di scale**»*.

Comment: Are you joking? Why would *ho sceso le scale* sound dialectal or childish? The transitive, non-regional use of *scendere* (as in *scendere le scale*, that is) is a perfectly good transitive verb, in all its tenses and moods: *scesi le scale*, *se avessi sceso le scale*, *scenderò le scale* and so on.

Comment: Hai ragione, mi sbaglio, non è dialettale, e le forme *se avessi sceso le scale* o *avrai sceso le scale* sono chiaramente corrette. Però le forme del passato e trapassato prossimo sono rarissime nella mia esperienza, mi suonano strane, infantili o estremamente colloquiali; ho chiesto anche ad altri nel frattempo e sono d'accordo... sarà la gente che conosco io :)
Mi sembra che anche l'OP trovi la forma strana. Suggerimenti per correggere la risposta?

Comment: Montale non la pensa come te e i tuoi interlocutori (sui quali presumibilmente grava un *sampling bias*): https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho_sceso,_dandoti_il_braccio,_almeno_un_milione_di_scale :-) Potresti eliminare gli ultimi due capoversi con l'ipotesi che “ho sceso le scale” sia dialettale (se non trovi prove a favore) e viceversa magari citare Montale, Goffredo Parise (“Allora sono tornato indietro, ho sceso le scale e sono uscito in strada”) o Federigo Tozzi (“il facchino mi ferma appeno ho sceso le scale”): sono i primi autori classici che trovo su Google Books.

Comment: @DaG, fbbdev, _scendere le scale_ è corretto e usato in tutte le sue forme, ma se a Milano dite _scendi lo zaino_ potreste suscitare ilarità (come per la famosa frase _scendi il cane che lo piscio_), direi di non insegnarlo agli stranieri...

Comment: @DaG sicuro che c'è *sampling bias*, è quello che volevo dire quando ho scritto "sarà la gente che conosco io" :). Però cercando su internet pare che ci sia un po' di confusione in merito. Credo che il frequente uso dialettale della forma la faccia percepire come errata a molti, incluso il sottoscritto.

Comment: Grazie per l'eccellente risposta! @CarLaTeX Non sono uno straniere, sono Italiano e sono di Torino, Ho posto questa domanda siccome "Ho sceso le scale" mi sembrava strano, Anche perché  mi sembrava un po' come dire "Ho sceso lo zaino" (frase sbagliatissima ma usata, purtroppo) quindi mi suonava abbastanza strano grammaticalmente. Comunque, grazie per la risposta che ha risolto i miei dubbi.

Comment: @user111444 Di niente. Se puoi/vuoi, magari edita il tuo profilo e metti un nickname, giusto per far capire subito che sei italiano. Ciao!

Comment: @CarLaTex I can't, I am on Android. I can't edit my nickname or my profile.